# 'ErrorType' is not convertible to 'NSError'

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics

I have an error with Google Analytics:

> 'ErrorType' is not convertible to 'NSError'; did you mean to use 'as!'
>   to force downcast?

It happen when I'm trying to call 2 times createScreenView

I do this:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {


        let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
        tracker.set(kGAIScreenName, value: "Demande Gratuite")

        var builder = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build() as! [NSObject : AnyObject]
        tracker.send(builder)
...
}

    @IBAction func Valider(sender: AnyObject) {
        ...
        let trackerv = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
        trackerv.set(kGAIScreenName, value: "Demande Envoyé")

        var builder = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build() as! [NSObject : AnyObject]
        trackerv.send(builder)


        let eventTracker: NSObject = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createItemWithTransactionId(
            "1",
            name: "test",
            sku: nil,
            category: "IOS",
            price: 1,
            quantity: 1,
            currencyCode: nil).build()
        trackerv.send(eventTracker as! [NSObject : AnyObject])
    }
```

Function where the error is:

```
lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    do {
        try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
    } catch {
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason

        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
        let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return coordinator
}()
```

Another problem here:

```
let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
tracker.set(kGAIScreenName, value: "Mentions Légales")

var builder = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build() as! [NSObject : AnyObject]
tracker.send(builder)
```

> Forced cast from 'NSMutableDictionary!' to '[NSObject : AnyObject]'
>   always succeeds; did you mean to use 'as'?

AND

> Variable 'builder' was never mutated; consider changing to 'let'
>   constant

Comment: You are not catching anything actually, try to right something like:
} catch let error = NSError {
}

Comment: @Array Wrong, when 'catch' is used alone like that, it automatically generates an ErrorType 'error' variable: you don't *have* to declare "catch let error as NSError". // However I also think that the ErrorType casting seems to be one of OP's problems, but not for the reason you give. :)

Comment: @EricD. But if I do only one createScreenView it work

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For me, this also happens when using **AVFoundation** and **Core Data** in the same project.

To get rid of the error:

> 'ErrorType' is not convertible to 'NSError'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?

Or the warnings:

> Conditional cast from 'ErrorType' to 'NSError' always succeeds
>
> Forced cast from 'ErrorType' to 'NSError' always succeeds; did you mean to use 'as'?

I did this:

```
lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("MY_APP_NAME.sqlite")
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    do {
        try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason

        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
        let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
        abort()
    } catch {
        // dummy
    }
    
    return coordinator
}()
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Spent wayyyy to much time to find what you did : a dummy `catch` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you the issue and suggests a solution. The constant `error` in the catch block is of type `ErrorType`, and you want to cast it to `NSError`, a cast which may not succeed. Therefore you cannot use the regular `as` operator which is only for casts that the compiler can tell will always succeed. Instead you either need to use `as!` to force-cast or `as?` to do a safe-cast.

```
catch {
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason

        if let underlyingError = error as? NSError {
            dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = underlyingError
        }
        let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }
```

For your second issue, you have the opposite problem. You are using the `as!` operator for a cast that the compiler knows will always work. You should just use the plain `as` operator. And the third issue is that you are declaring a variable (`var`) whose value you never change. In those cases, using a constant (`let`) is preferred.

```
let builder = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build() as [NSObject : AnyObject]
```

Comment: A variable of type `ErrorType` can always be converted with `as NSError`.  The persistentStoreCoordinator method as presented in the question is standard template code from Xcode and *does compile as is*. An optional cast is not necessary in this case.

Comment: @MartinR Interesting, thanks! Not sure why Ben is getting the compiler error though. Different Swift version maybe?

Comment: Interestingly enough, for me this error started to appear right in the middle of development, in Core Data code which I did not even touched between builds. I made "Clean project" many times before without error, and after, but error continued to appear. Compiler just stopped to understand Xcode-generated code. Finally, i was need to change `as` cast. No idea what it was, looks as rare compiler bug.