# Creating extension causes 'ErrorType' is not convertible to 'NSError'

Tags: swift, error-handling, nsdecimalnumber

I've been playing with `NSDecimalNumber` and when I created an extension, all of a sudden I was getting this error:

> 'ErrorType' is not convertible to 'NSError'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?

But when I use `as!` as suggested, I'm getting the warning:

> Forced cast from 'NSMutableDictionary!' to '[NSObject : AnyObject]' always succeeds; did you mean to use 'as'?

Eventually changing to `as?` is giving me:

> Conditional cast from 'ErrorType' to 'NSError' always succeeds

The extension I created is:

```
extension String {

    var decimalValue: NSDecimalNumber? {
        let number = NSDecimalNumber(string: self)

        return number == NSDecimalNumber.notANumber() ? nil : number
    }
}
```

The code that causes the error is:

```
lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
    let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent(self.storeFile)
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."

    do {
        try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
    } catch {
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
--->    dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError    <---

        let error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)

        NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return coordinator
}()
```

When I change the extension this error will be gone:

```
var decimalValue: NSDecimalNumber? {
    return NSDecimalNumber(string: self)
}
```

How should I make this extension without getting this annoying warning / error?

Comment: Have you tried } catch let error as NSError { instead of dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError  ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Answer actually the message is very clear. The ErrorType is an empty protocol and it's been adopted by the NSError. Therefore there is no need to "guard" or "if let" it again. you can simply say

```
let underlyingError = error as NSError
```

And the warning will just disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about why it is causing warning just because you are adding extension to `String`, but we can take care of warning!

As [this SO post answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34722649/errortype-is-not-convertible-to-nserror), we can do this:

```
lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
    ....
    do {
         try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        ....
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
        let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        ....
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
        abort()
    } catch {
        // dummy
    }

    return coordinator
}()
```

Key factor is catch error like **`catch let error as NSError`**